# Tail call optimisation in Elixir

Tags: elixir

Little help needed on clearing the concept of Tail call optimisation. As far as i understand `Tail call optimisation` only works when you call a recursive function as your last statement. Here are my 2 examples and i am not sure if both are tail call optimised or not.

With an intermediate result variable

```
    def map(list, fun) do
        do_map(list,fun,[])
    end
    defp do_map([],_fun,result) do
        result
    end
    defp do_map([h|t],fun,_result) do
        result = fun.(h)
        do_map(t,fun,result)
    end
end
```

WITHOUT an intermediate result variable. Will it be considered as `Tail call optimised` ?

```
defmodule MyList do
    def map(list, fun) do
        do_map(list,fun,[])
    end
    defp do_map([],_fun,result) do
        result
    end
    defp do_map([h|t],fun,_result) do
        do_map(t,fun,fun.(h))
    end
end
```

Comment: Yes, both are TCO. The latter evaluates arguments and only then calls `do_map/3`. The code above does not map anything, though. To indeed map you want the latter to be `defp do_map([h|t], fun, result), do: do_map(t, fun, [fun.(h)|result])`.

Comment: yes indeed , Thank you. I changed it in my code. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, both examples of yours are TCO because the recursive function `do_map` is the [last operation](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2016-October/090663.html), as all arguments in Elixir are evaluated first. The only way to make it not TCO is by calling the recursive function before the final operation.

With TCO:

```
defmodule MyList do
  def map(list, fun) do
    do_map(list, fun, [])
  end
  defp do_map([], _fun, result) do
    Enum.reverse(result)
  end
  defp do_map([h|t], fun, result) do
    do_map(t, fun, [fun.(h) | result])
  end
end
```

Without TCO:

```
defmodule MyList do
  def map(list, fun) do
    do_map(list, fun)
  end
  defp do_map([], _fun) do
    []
  end
  defp do_map([h|t], fun) do
    # The final call is the list append operation
    [fun.(h) | do_map(t, fun)]
  end
end
```

Keep in mind that Tail Call Optimized functions in Erlang [might not always be faster](https://pragtob.wordpress.com/2016/06/16/tail-call-optimization-in-elixir-erlang-not-as-efficient-and-important-as-you-probably-think/). The main purpose of TCO in erlang is due to it's use in [process top-loops](https://elixirforum.com/t/tail-call-optimization-in-elixir-erlang-not-as-efficient-and-important-as-you-probably-think/880/3), such as `gen_server`'s `enter_loop`.

If your function **never** returns then you *must* to use TCO as you can blow the stack. Otherwise you might just be saving yourself some stack space and additional GC runs by writing TCO functions.